# How to send mails using windows service when it gets message from a windows application and response back the percentage of works done?

Tags: c#

I have a windows application in which I'm saving files in database and I need to notify windows service which is located on the same network to mail these files and the windows service need to respond back with percentage of works done to the application.This windows service is currently using for purposes like notify who is logged in and from which IP address.How can I accomplish my task without effecting current functionality of Windows service?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write a second service and possibly integrate both into one service at a later point in time?